# An ad with Dynamic Experience only support Traffic and Conversions campaign objectives

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I use facebook-business-php 17.0.1

I successfully created campaign, adset and creative through sdk (this scheme using asset_feed_spec https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-creative/placement-asset-customization), and finally create ads The error, my campaign is OUTCOME_APP_PROMOTION, this is fixed, there is no other choice, is this not a new promotion target? Doesn't it support the asset_feed_spec way yet?

I hope to provide an example, by using facebook-business-php 17.0.1